# Unable to install JDK 1.6

Tags: java

When executing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

executing displays following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-6-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openjdk-6-jre' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless`?

Comment: Why don't you try 1.7?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Looks like there is no `openjdk-6-jre` for Ubuntu 12.10

You may see at [java packages page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/java/) that there is only `openjdk-7-jre` available.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install java-common

sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless

java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be resolved by opening  software center. Click on 'edit' and then 'software sources' to open the software sources window. Once that is open, check the box that says, "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)." like

[image: Ubuntu Software Center preference]

And then install Open-jdk as suggested by others-

If problem still persists try Oracle Java, as am using Oracle Java and everyone knows what’s the difference between both ,So its better to go with latest Oracle Java

## Completely remove Open-jdk

just use this simple commands in terminal to remove open jdk completely

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*
```

## How to install Oracle-Java

To get an automatically update-able Java from Oracle, you can you use the PPA provided from webup8.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

## Installing Oracle Java manually

**For installing Latest Oracle Java:**

To check ubuntu system architecture installed

```
$ uname -m
```

or

```
$ arch
```

Download the Oracle Java JDK for Linux. Make sure you select the correct compressed binaries for your system architecture 32-bit or 64-bit (which end in tar.gz).It will be downloaded in Downloads folder in home.So first open nautilus with sudo as

```
sudo nautilus
```

and make a folder java under

```
/usr/local/
```

and then folow the following commands:

```
cd /home/"your_user_name"/Downloads
sudo cp -r jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java
cd /usr/local/java
sudo chmod a+x jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo tar xvzf jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

At this point you should have two uncompressed binary directories in /usr/local/java check it by

```
ls -a
```

Now edit the system path file by

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

scroll down to the last and add following lines

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

Save and exit and write these commands in terminal to Inform your Ubuntu Linux system where your Oracle Java JDK/JRE is located.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaws" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaws
. /etc/profile
```

Now everything is installed just check it by

```
java -version
```

the output must be like

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b40)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Congratulation now its installed.